# Syntax error, unrecognized expression. Jquery Selectors after upgrade to new version

Tags: jquery, razor, jquery-selectors

I have upgraded Jquery from 1.7.1 to 1.11.1. Now I started getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #refdialog :input[data-fieldname='CODE'][data-bookmark='2'][data-bo'REF_OKATO']
```

At this line:

```
$("input[data-fieldname='" + depFields[i] + "']").attr("value", $("#refdialog :input[data-fieldname='" + sourceFields[i].toUpperCase() + "'][data-bookmark='" + bookmark + "'][data-bo'" +
                    $("input[data-fieldname='" + depFields[i] + "']").data("reference").toUpperCase() + "']").attr("value"));
```

I'm using asp.net mvc Razor.

Here is error demonstration page, look at console: http://jsfiddle.net/n8bver46/ If you change Jquery version to 1.7 then it will work fine.

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It should be `"'][data-bo='"`, not `"'][data-bo'"`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8bver46/2/)

Comment: Holy crap! I'm a donkey. Thanks

Comment: @Sibay you're welcome. I actually don't know why 1.7.1 doesn't generate error. Maybe it simply doesn't handle multipe `[]`...